# Proper way of running an event when a dynamically rendered Iframe ends in react

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-native, iframe

I am currently torn between two possible options to run an event when my dynamically rendered Iframe embed (cross-site) finishes in react. I can either use reacts built in onEnded event which I can't seem to get working or I can try to make my own onEnded event which uses the aria values of the iframe element in the DOM to calculate when the embed ends. Which one should I choose and in as much detail as possible how would I implement it?

Comment: Use iframe element load event

Comment: @charlietfl I already tried the load event in react and it surprisingly works well but I need an event that fires when the embed ends not when it loads. Unless you mean something else?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "ends"? Load event means the whole iframe page has loaded all the main resources

Comment: @charlietfl When the embed inside the Iframe ends. My iframes are either soundcloud embeds, or youtube embeds, so whenever the soundcloud song ends or the youtube video ends the event should fire.

Comment: Ok...none of that was clear in the question. You will need to use API's provided by those media sources.

Comment: @charlietfl I would prefer not using the API's, certainly there must be a way to do it independently no? If not with reacts built in events could I at least search the document after every render and find the values of the progress bar?

Comment: Not likely since you can't access cross origin iframes for security reasons

Comment: @charlietfl Are you sure? When I inspect the iframe element in my browser I can see all the values and properties inside the iframe including the timing properties which I can use to deduce when an embed has ended. I should be able to latch onto these whenever the component re renders. I'm just unfamiliar with how to query a document in react. Do you have any thoughts on where I should start when trying to select DOM elements in react. I will get back to you and close this question if I manage to do it.

Comment: Not with javascript you can't, that I am sure of. An iframe has it's own window and document and those are unreachable from parent page code unless you control code in both which you clearly don't

Comment: @charlietfl Ok I think I see what you mean, there is a document tag inside my DOM tree which I assume encapsulates the other domains page. I greatly appreciate your ability to proof read my ideas so I have one more I would like to pass by you. Could I somehow periodically fetch the entire document I am embedding inside the iframe and query select that instead? I have done something similar to actually get some information from the youtube videos from their URL's and was wondering If it would be possible to do the same with embedded videos. I'd just need a way to ajax or fetch the document.

Comment: Short answer is no. The cross origin iframe is a complete black box with regard to parent page script. You can't even tell if user navigates to another page inside the iframe. Over the years iframes have been used very maliciously. You need the sdk from those media sources